# Left and right arrow crashes FilthyPillow in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

I'm using [FilthyPillow](https://github.com/aef-/jquery.filthypillow) JQuery plugin.

In IE8 it crashes when you try to use right or left arrow between the date and time sections.

Any ideas how to fix?

Sample code from website:

```
var $fp = $( ".filthypillow-1" ),
    now = moment( ).subtract( "seconds", 1 );
$fp.filthypillow( { 
  minDateTime: function( ) {
    return now;
  } 
} );
$fp.on( "focus", function( ) {
  $fp.filthypillow( "show" );
} );
$fp.on( "fp:save", function( e, dateObj ) {
  $fp.val( dateObj.format( "MMM DD YYYY hh:mm A" ) );
  $fp.filthypillow( "hide" );
} );
```

Comment: With issues relating to a plugin you are best to contact the author directly. Especially when you don't show any code to recreate the problem.

Comment: It fails in this fashion using their demo code. Yes, I will contact them too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a way around this.

It is crashing on an Array.IndexOf which IE8 does not have.

So including the Polyfill found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) brings this functionality to IE8 and allows FilthyPillow to work as expected.